# Getting a config error when using facebook mobile for my web app

Tags: iphone, facebook, web-applications, mobile

I am at a loss. I have a facebook game which has no problems on the desktop. I have created a mobile web app for the game but when I turn on the mobile section of the app and try to navigate to the game through the facebook iPhone app I get an error saying:

"The mobile version  of the app is unavailable because it is misconfigured for mobile access."

Apparently this is not happening on Android phones. Only on iPhones and iPads.

I can navigate to the web app through my mobile browser and it works fine.

Please help!

Comment: did you follow the official facebook iOS integration?

Comment: Yes, is there something specific or a specific link you are referring to?

Comment: this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/ ?

Comment: @Shubhank The question specifically refers to mobile web app and not a native app. So the above link doesn't help. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are correct. I have not built a native iphone app yet, only a mobile web app.

Comment: you kinda of just proved me wrong :D..my bad..

Comment: What happens is when you search for and go to the app through the facebook iphone app it goes through a cycle m.facebook...,my mobile web app address,facebook.com...,apps.facebook.com...

and it does this two or three times and then I get the error, however on Android phones it goes through the cycle once and comes to the page

Comment: I am using facebook PHP SDK to login built through codeIgniter